# Any way to set Visual Studio 2010 locale to English without installing/uninstalling? (aka. How to change decimal separator from dot to comma?)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, double, locale

I've checked similar questions and I've noted that most solutions involve re-installing VS or installing packages that resolve this issue, I'm looking for a way to fix this issue by adjusting settings if possible, so please don't submit any answers that involve installing/uninstalling.

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7, I've set the locale to English so it defaults most messages to English but I've got the "Formats" and "Language" set to Swedish/Sweden (see Control Panel > Region and Language).
The problem I'm having is for example that I have to type double values as 2,0 instead of 2.0, I want to be able to type the dot as a separator for decimals and not the comma.

`bool b = double.tryParse("2.0", out dbl);`

Returns false and the value of dbl is not changed because VS on my machine doesn't recognize . as a decimal separator, instead I have to write this:

`bool b = double.tryParse("2,0", out dbl);`

Returns true and assigns 2.0 to the dbl variable, because my machine recognizes , as a decimal separator.

Comment: Type into what?  Not Visual Studio I imagine.  Your program will default to the machine's default language and culture settings.  Swedes use a comma.  Pass CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to Double.Parse() if you want to use a point.

Comment: Yes I want to type dots into VS and have it read it as a decimal separator. Is there any way to override VS loading the default language and instead ALWAYS have it load English UK/US?
I don't want to have to use the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture workaround everytime, I want a permanent fix, hopefully without installing any new components.

Comment: You have to be more specific.  Make a screenshot of VS and draw a big red arrow pointing at where you want to enter decimals with a period.  Why you wouldn't just change the machine setting is unclear to me.

Comment: Do you mean that I should change the machine settings for the whole OS? That seems like overkill since the only thing I want to do is for VS to load another locale.
I'll edit in an example in my questions to further specify the problem.

Comment: That's got nothing to do with VS.  Use InvariantCulture like I explained before: double.TryParse("2.0", NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out dbl);

Comment: Ok, guess that will have to do.. It's kind of bad that depending on which machine you run you may or may not get an exception/error or improper behaviour just because the machines locale is different.
When I was programming in Java on NetBeans I never had this kind of problems, but then again VS and C# is more platform dependant.
The way it's right now VS loads settings in the following manner:
**"machine:locale --> VS:loadDefaultLocale()"**
It'd be better if it could go:
**"machine:locale --> VS:loadFromSettings(differentLocale)"**
If you get my point. :)